# How to remove leading zeros from Integer in Java?

Tags: java, integer

I have a given Integer which starts with one 0 or multiples. This changes the Value of the Integer because in converts it to another Number.

```
int a = 0400;
return a / 4;
```

Output is :

```
64
```

How can i turn padding 0 number to normal int?0400 should be 400.

Comment: `int a = 400;`?

Comment: I have the feeling a part of the question/context is missing.. If not, it's indeed as @Eran above suggests.. :/ PS: `0400` is actually an octal number with base-10 value `256`.

Comment: How are the values given, in a string format ?

Comment: The Integer is given. I have to Convert it.

Answer (score 4):

If

```
int a = 0400;
```

is given, and you have to convert it to the value 400, you can convert it to a `String` in radix 8 and then parse it back to `int` (which will use radix 10 by default):

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a,8));
System.out.println(b);
```

prints

```
400
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Was about to post an answer with [the same conversion](https://ideone.com/nKkqzY).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 cases

- If you have `0400` as an int you may pass througt a `String` specifying `8` radix, then parse back to `int`

  ```
    int a = 0400
    int res = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a,8));
  ```
- If you have it as `String` like `"0400"` just use `Integer.parseInt`

  ```
    String a = "0400"
    int res = Integer.parseInt(a);
  ```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` uses base-10 as default conversion, so `int a = Integer.parseInt("0400");` already holds value `400`: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoMwFEV3v@LiFIeGDN2kH9Chk2Pp8KpBYuMzJE@hFL89jU6XwznciTa6TMMn595TSniQ418FhPXtXY8kJGW2xQ2Yi1KdRMfj8wVqjgxwLGDccGexo406UEy2gKrN1Zi6ac@q@yaxs15W0aEciGfFp9qrPec/). No need for the replace.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh yep, I was missing that ^^

Comment: These seems to work.Thanks!!!!